# Проблема при проверке регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Не могу проверить банальное выражения. Результат `Not matched!`

Что не хватает в данном коде ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doMatch("abc");
}


public static void doMatch(String value){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(value + " Matched!"+" "+ matcher.matches());
    } else if(!(matcher.matches())){
        System.out.println(value + " :Not matched!"+" "+    matcher.matches());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша регулярка ищет лишь единственное вхождение символа из диапазонов `a-zA-Z`
Например, при вызове`matcher.find()` вам вернется `true` и будет три совпадения - `a`, `b`, `c`. `matcher.matches()` вернет `true` когда вся строка целиком будет подходить под регулярку. Для этого вам нужно сделать регулярку например, такой: `[a-zA-Z]+`